# How define a boundary in matplotlib python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot the following field equations:

- dx/dt = x*(4*y+3*x-3)
- dy/dt = y*(4*y+3*x-4)

but I do not  know how can I restrict the boundary to a triangle: `x>=0, y>=0, x<=1-y`:

[image]

```
# stream plot with matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def velocity_i(x,y):
    vx = x*(3*x+4*y-3)
    vy = y*(3*x+4*y-4)
    return vx, vy
n=100
x = np.linspace(0, 1, n)
y = np.linspace(0, 1, n)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Ux, Uy = velocity_i(X, Y)
vels = (Ux**2+Uy**2)**0.5
plt.figure(figsize=(5,4))
stream = plt.streamplot(X, Y,
              Ux,Uy,
              arrowsize=1,
              arrowstyle='->',
              color= vels,
              density=1,
              linewidth=1,
                       )
plt.xlabel(r"$\Omega_{\rm m}$",fontsize='14')
plt.ylabel(r"$\Omega_{\rm r}$",fontsize='14')
plt.colorbar(stream.lines)

plt.xlim((-.05,1.05))
plt.ylim((-.05,1.05))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please select the posted answer

Comment: @MadPhysicist: I have reminded the OP couple of times as he seemed a new user. But he asked me a new question on 3d which is a completely different task. So I quit asking :)

Comment: @Bazingaa. Positive reinforcement doesn't always work :)

Answer (score 4):

This is quite straightforwardly achievable using NumPy masking and [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) function. I am only showing the relevant two lines of code (highlighted by a comment) needed to get the job done.

**Explanation**: `X<=1-Y` checks your required boundary condition and then at all those indices where this condition holds `True`, it assigns the actual computed value of `Ux` (or `Uy`) and at indices where the condition is `False`, it assigns 0. Here `X<=1-Y` acts as kind of a conditional mask.

```
Ux, Uy = velocity_i(X, Y)
Ux = np.where(X<=1-Y, Ux, 0) # <--- Boundary condition for Ux
Uy = np.where(X<=1-Y, Uy, 0) # <--- Boundary condition for Uy
vels = (Ux**2+Uy**2)**0.5
```

[image]

Comment: Then, how can we plot 3d: 
dx/dt = x*(4*y+3*x+2*z-3) , 
dy/dt = y*(4*y+3*x+2*z-4) , 
dz/dt = z*(4*y+3*x+2*z-2) , 
for between x,y,z>=0 and  x+y+z=1 ?

Comment: That's a new problem. You wanted to get the plot similar to what you posted in the question. I helped you with that. Post a new question for a 3d. Show in your new question, what is the expected 3d output. On Stack overflow you ask one question at a time. Plotting 3d would require some thoughts and efforts. People will help you if you first show them your attempt. No one will write a code from scratch for you.

Comment: Plz see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53995222/boundary-in-3d-vector-field-plot

Comment: Would it be useful to select `X` and `Y` before you compute `Ux` and `Uy` to begin with?

Comment: @MadPhysicist: I tried that using `Ux, Uy = velocity_i(X[X<=1-Y], Y[X<=1-Y])` but then X and Y are meshgrid and so for me the straightforward solution was to simply assign 0 values later. Choosing `X, Y = np.meshgrid(x[x<1-y], y[x<1-y])` would be wrong