# Filter out a circle boundary in matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot the electric field generated when an spheric conductor is placed in an homogeneous electric field. I based my code on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53988824/how-define-a-boundary-in-matplotlib-python) to use np.where function to filter out the unitary circle. But instead of that, all of the field at -1< x<1 is filtered out.

[image: Image I got]

My code is shown below, how can I fix this?

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.constants as spc

def E(x, y):
    """due to an spheric conductor set on a homogeneous electric field"""
    E_x = 3*x*y/((y**2+x**2)**2.5)
    E_y = 3*y*y/((y**2+x**2)**2.5)-1/((y**2+x**2)**1.5)+1
    return E_x, E_y

# Grid of x, y points
n= 100
a=2
y = np.linspace(-a, a, n)
x = np.linspace(-a, a, n)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
r=(x**2+y**2)**0.5
circle = r>=1
Ex, Ey = E(X,Y)
Ex, Ey = np.where(circle,Ex,0), np.where(circle,Ey,0)

#plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

color = 2 * np.log(np.hypot(Ex, Ey))
ax.streamplot(x, y, Ex, Ey, color=color, linewidth=1, cmap=plt.cm.inferno,
              density=1, arrowstyle='->', arrowsize=1.5)

ax.set_ylabel('$y$')
ax.set_xlabel('$x$')
ax.set_ylim(-a,a)
ax.set_xlim(-a,a)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your `r` array to use in the circle filter, you are using the 1D `x` and `y` arrays, when you should be using the 2D `X` and `Y` arrays.

Change that line from

```
r = (x**2 + y**2)**0.5
```

to

```
r = (X**2 + Y**2)**0.5
```

and it works as expected

[image]

Comment: Oh I totally ignored that small detail. Thank you very much for pointing that out.